# Calling a sound with javascript is not working onf firefox

Tags: javascript, audio

Hi,

I am calling a mp3 sound with javascript which produces a request like this:

GET XHR http://example.net/chat//hurry.mp3 [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 160ms]

the sound is perfectly heard on other browsers but not firefox.

why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: Requesting an audio does not mean the browser should play it. Could you add the code on how you "call" the MP3?

Comment: But why is it played on all other browsers? I am not sure bout the code. Is it possible to get it via devtools from the console?

Comment: Where is your actual code, @CainNuke? You've not shown anything that lets us understand how you're actually "calling an mp3 sound with javascript", and what you might be doing wrong there for it to not work in at least one browser.

Comment: Thats a hard one because I didnt make the code. Its from a script I downloaded and it seems quite complicated. I am trying to debug it but I only have devtools to do that.

Comment: Hello??? Help please!!!

Comment: Hey! Please help!! I tried all!

Comment: HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEY!! What about some HELP????? HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEELP!!!!!